# Bold math in Context

Tags: context, context-mkiv

I am not able to get bold math symbols using context.

Details: I am using Tex-live 2012 distribution. Compiled using `context main.tex` which means I am using `context mkiv`. Log file shows the version as
ConTeXt  ver: 2012.05.30.

UPDATE: Following MWE works with `texexec` i.e. `context mkii`.

**MWE**

```
%As suggested at contextgarden.net for getting bold math.
\definetypeface [boldmath] [mm] [boldmath] [latin-modern] [default]

\starttext
\startformula
\boldsymbol{\alpha} = \alpha
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\bf` works fine in math if you load Latin Modern OpenType math fonts (which was not done by default in TeX Live version).

```
\setupbodyfont[modern] % not needed with ConTeXt minimals
\starttext
\startformula
{\bf\alpha} = \alpha
\stopformula
\stoptext
```

Comment: There is also `\bi` if you want bold italic.